# what does the text "d=x.x" mean in graphs generated by s.label {ade4} by r

Tags: r, data-visualization

When generating figures by s.label, text "d=x.x" will should up on the top right corner of the plot (see plot below). What does this number mean?

The plot is generated with the following code:

```
library(ade4)

layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 2), 2, 2))

data(atlas)

s.label(atlas$xy, lab = atlas$names.district, area = atlas$area, 
        inc = FALSE, addax = FALSE)
```

I have checked this link for documentation on s.label http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/ade4/ade4-html/s.label.html

[image: this is a figure generated by s.label]

Comment: I don't know, but I'd guess it's the scale - the distance between the grid lines in some units or other.